# Superscript in CSS only?

Tags: css

How can I get superscript done, only in CSS?

I have a stylesheet where I mark the external links with a superscript character, but I'm having a hard time getting the character aligned correctly.

What I have currently, looks like this:

```
a.external:after {
  font-size: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  content: "+";
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Naturally, I'd use the `<sup>`-tag, only if `content` would allow for HTML...

Comment: The "vertical-align:text-top" did not work for me in IE9. But, it did in FireFox 4.0. At least within a Wordpress context.

Comment: If `content` allowed HTML, separation of concerns would suffer.

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering  ... "***Separation of Concerns** (SoC) is a design principle for separating a computer program into distinct sections such that each section addresses a separate concern. A concern is a set of information that affects the code of a computer program."* ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)) 

Answer (score 584, accepted):

You can do superscript with  [**`vertical-align: super`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align), (plus an accompanying [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size) reduction).

However,  be sure to **read the other answers** here, particularly those by [paulmurray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only#572967) and [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only#501689), for useful information.

Comment: Also, the `font-size` has to be reduced to give the actual superscript effect.

Comment: @paulmurray's answer below is more accurate and comprehensive.  IMHO, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Saying "below" doesn't tend to help when there are three different ways of ordering answers.

You're right though, [paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only#answer-572967) _is_ a better one, and it's crazy this has over five times as many votes.

Answer (score 218):

Honestly I don't see the point in doing superscript/subscript in CSS only.  There's no handy CSS attribute for it, just a bunch of homegrown implementations including:

```
.superscript { position: relative; top: -0.5em; font-size: 80%; }
```

or using vertical-align or I'm sure other ways.  Thing is, it starts to get complicated:

- [CSS superscript spacing](http://www.xs4all.nl/%7Esbpoley/webmatters/superscripts.html) on line height;
- [Beware CSS for Superscript/Subcript](https://web.archive.org/web/20230102153347/http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/tlt/2007/02/beware_css_for_superscriptsubc.html) on why you arguably shouldn't style superscript/subscript with CSS **at all**;

The second point is worth emphasizing.  Typically superscript/subscript is not actually a styling issue but is indicative of meaning.

**Side note:** It's worth mentioning this [list of entities for common mathematical superscript and subscript expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160922000043/http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html) even though this question doesn't relate to that.

The sub/sup tags are in HTML and XHTML.  I would just use those.

As for the rest of your CSS, the :after pseudo-element and content attributes are not widely supported.  If you really don't want to put this manually in the HTML I think a Javascript-based solution is your next best bet.  With jQuery this is as simple as:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.external").append("<sup>+</sup>");
};
```

Comment: With "not widely supported" you mean "not supported in IE", I suppose?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html not supported in IE7 and lower or in IE8 in compatibility mode.

Comment: ...which is quite exactly what I said, yes.

Comment: To simplify wrapping an A tag with a SUP tag, use the following: $("a.external").wrap("<sup />");

Comment: This worked best for me as I wanted to style a :after-text that my class should append to a form label in order to indicate "something special" :-)

Comment: Used the accepted solution by @PeterBoughton at first, opted for this one as it does not skew line-height.

Comment: Maybe you can't see the point because you don't know the requirements and the context. I have a system that wraps `<span class="superscript"></span>` instead of `<sup>` and it would be easier to implement that in CSS than to rewrite the system. In other words, what I'm trying to say, is that whether it makes sense of doing  superscript in CSS or in HTML is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: I would love to use SUP, but it doesn't position a TM symbol correctly. The height is usually wrong, depending on the text size.

Comment: Both links in your bullet pointed list appear to be broken.

Answer (score 146):

The CSS documentation contains industry-standard CSS equivalent for all HTML constructs. That is: most web browsers these days do not explicitly handle `SUB`, `SUP`, `B`, `I` and so on - they (kinda sorta) are converted into `SPAN` elements with appropriate CSS properties, and the rendering engine only deals with that.

The page is [Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)

The bits you want are:

```
small, sub, sup { font-size: .83em }
sub             { vertical-align: sub }
sup             { vertical-align: super }
```

Comment: This works, but it screws up `line-height`. IMHO the only way not to screw up `line-height` is to use `position:relative` as suggested by cletus: http://stackoverflow.com/a/501689/260080

Comment: The following code seems to do the trick: `sub { vertical-align: sub; line-height: 1.0; }` for subscripts and `sup { vertical-align: super; line-height: 1.0; }` for superscripts. No need to bother with positioning.

Answer (score 28):

I was working on a page with the aim of having clearly legible text, with superscript elements NOT changing the line's top and bottom margins - with the following observations:

If for your main text you have `line-height: 1.5em` for example, you should reduce the line-height of your superscript text for it to appear correctly. I used `line-height: 0.5em`.

Also, `vertical-align: super` works well in most browsers but in IE8 when you have a superscript element present, the rest of that line is pushed down. So instead I used `vertical-align: baseline` together with a negative `top` and `position: relative` to achieve the same effect, which seems to work better across browsers.

So, to add to the "homegrown implementations":

```
.superscript {
    font-size: .83em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4em;
}
```

Comment: this cuts off when placed in div container

Answer (score 17):

The following is taken from Mozilla Firefox's internal html.css:

```
sup {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

So, in your case it would be something, like:

```
.superscript {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: But the default SUP element doesn't correctly align a TM symbol vertically.

Answer (score 15):

http://htmldog.com/articles/superscript/ Essentially:

```
position: relative;
bottom: 0.5em;
font-size: 0.8em;
```

Works well in practice, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm using this in a Web page for TM symbols. It works well once the two constants are tuned for the font used. I use top with a negative offset instead of bottom with a positive offset, since the TM symbol is aligned with the top of the preceding character.

Answer (score 8):

This is another clean solution:

```
sub, sup {vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; font-size: 70%;} /* 70% size of its parent element font-size which is good. */
sub {bottom: -0.6em;} /* use em becasue they adapt to parent font-size */
sup {top: -0.6em;} /* use em becasue they adapt to parent font-size */
```

In this way you **can still use sup/sub** tags but you **fixed their idious behavior to always screw up paragraph line height**.

So now you can do:

```
  <p>This is a line of text.</p>
  <p>This is a line of text, <sub>with sub text.</sub></p>
  <p>This is a line of text, <sup>with sup text.</sup></p>
  <p>This is a line of text.</p>
```

And your paragraph line height should not get screwed up.

Tested on IE7, IE8, FF3.6, SAFARI4, CHROME5, OPERA9

I tested using a `p {line-height: 1.3;}` (that is a good line height unless you want your lines to stick too close) and it still works, cause "-0.6em" is such a small amount that also with that line height the sub/sub text will fit and don't go over each other.

Forgot a detail that might be relevant I always use DOCTYPE in the **1st line of my page** (specifically I use the HTML 4.01 `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`). So I don't know if this solution works well when browser is in quirkmode (or not standard mode) due to lack of DOCTYPE or to a DOCTYPE that does not triggers Standard/Almost Standard mode.

Comment: Despite the answer being ten years old, it's still the right way to do this. `postition:relative;` keeps the browser from screwing up all the paragraph `line-height` assignments. This default behavior is so weird it strikes me as being a bug in rendering model of HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you are changing the font size, you might want to stop shrinking sizes with this rule:

```
sup sub, sub sup, sup sup, sub sub{font-size:1em !important;}
```

Answer (score 4):

The CSS property `font-variant-position` is under consideration and may eventually be the answer to this question. As of early 2017, only Firefox supports it, though.

```
.super {
    font-variant-position: super;
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-position).

Comment: It’s spring 2020 and still not supported by any browser but Firefox. Ah so…

Answer (score 2):

try

```
.aftersup {
 font-size: 1em;
 margin: left;
 vertical-align: .7em;
}
```

or plain "after"

```
.after {
 font-size: 1em;
 margin: left;
 vertical-align: .7em;
}
```

".a.external:after" could be simplified

or

```
.after {
 font-size: 50%;
 margin: left;
 vertical-align: .7em;
}
```

using "font size 50%" - 50% of what size? this might not work well if not used within some tag defining text size previous to superscript...

if you use "font-size: 1em;"  then the font size is set for sure, without reference to a tag that defines link text size, unless link text is set at 100% and superscript is 50% of that 100%.

Using "font-size: 1em;" actually sets font size baseline.

Set "vertical-align" size smaller, if you want superscript font to be smaller than link text

Set "vertical-align" size same as font size, if you want superscript font to be same size as link text

To align with link text, you need to set "margin" same as link text (left, center, right, justified).

```
.text {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: left;
}
.aftersup {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: left;
  vertical-align: .7em;
}
```

It should be something like below example links with <sup>superscript</sup>

```
<p class="text"><a href="url">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only</a><aftersup>+</aftersup></p>
```

or

```
<p class="text"><a href="url">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only</a><aftersup>You got this</aftersup></p>
```

or

```
<a href="url">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only</a><aftersup>+</aftersup>
```

or

```
<a href="url">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only<aftersup>You got this</aftersup>
```

As in...

[Superscript in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)+

or

[Superscript in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)You got this

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.cssdesignpatterns.com/Chapter%2012%20-%20ALIGNING%20CONTENT/Vertical-aligned%20Content/example.html

if looks like you want "vertical-align:text-top"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is related but I have solved my problem with  `&sup2;` HTML entities as I wasn't able to add any other html tags inside a `<label>` tag. So the idea was using ASCII codes instead of css or HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
.superscript {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 90%;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact way sup uses:

```
.superscript{
    vertical-align:super;
    font-size:smaller;
}
```

Found this via google chrome inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

Related or maybe not related, using superscript as a HTML element or as a span+css in text might cause problem with localization - in localization programs.

For example let's say "3<sup>rd</sup> party software":

```
3<sup>rd</sup> party software
3<span class="superscript">rd</span> party software
```

How can translators translate "rd"? They can leave it empty for several cyrrilic languages, but what about of other exotic or RTL languages?

In this case it is better to avoid using superscripts and use a full wording like "third-party software".
Or, as mentioned here in other comments, adding plus signs in superscript via jQuery.