# How do I make footnotes in restructured text look like superscripts without the brackets?

Tags: css, restructuredtext

I'm a beginner in both CSS and reStructuredText. I'm writing in reST and exporting to HTML. The syntax for footnotes that I'm using is `[#]_`, which, in the HTML generated, shows up as `[1]`. I'd like footnotes to instead appear as superscripts. reST assigns a class to all footnotes in the HTML written, so I can probably utilize this and make use of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only) to get footnote references superscripted. However, how do I strip them of the `[]` brackets?

Answer (score 5):

How are you converting your reStructuredText to HTML? If you are using [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) then the HTML writer has a command line option `--footnote-references` which selects between brackets or superscript references (the default being brackets). To use superscript references simply pass

```
--footnote-references 'superscript'
```

when invoking Docutils.

You could alternatively subclass the `Writer` class in `path_to_docutils/docutils/writers/html4css1/__init__.py` and have whatever formatting for your footnotes you like.

Comment: A third way: if you're using `docutils.core.publish_parts()`, call it like so:

     `docutils.core.publish_parts(..., settings_overrides={'footnote_references': 'superscript'})`