# Accessibility of using <sup> to indicate powers (such as 4^2)?

Tags: html, accessibility, superscript

Is using the `<sup>` tag the proper way to indicate powers? In a screen reader, wouldn't `3<sup>2</sup>` just read as three-two or thirty-two? It seems like there has to be a more accessible way to do this.

Comment: Actually, screen readers should be aware of that and read it out correct.

Comment: Yeah, I believe most screen readers will read that as "three superscript two"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In general**, when there is an Unicode equivalent for the [subscript/superscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript), you *should* use that character directly instead of the `sub`/`sup` element (it's not a *must*, just a recommendation, so go on using whatever you like more).

You can find some of those subscripted/superscripted Unicode characters in these Wikipedia articles:

- [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)
- [Latin-1 Supplement (Unicode block)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) (for `¹`, `²` and `³`)
- [Phonetic symbols in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_symbols_in_Unicode)

You could enter (or copy/paste) these chars directly in your document, if you set the charset to an Unicode encoding like UTF-8. Example for HTML5: `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Otherwise you'd use [character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Exception: **in a mathematical context**, you *should* use [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) with `msub`/`msup` (so don't use these special subscripted/superscripted Unicode characters there). You can use MathML in HTML5 within the [`math`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/mathml.html#mathml) element.

Source for these two "*shoulds*": [**Unicode in XML and other Markup Languages**: 5.6 Superscripts and Subscripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/NOTE-unicode-xml-20070516/#Superscripts) ([via blog post in German](http://untief.org/blog/2012/08/hochstellung-tiefstellung-html-oder-unicode))

> It seems like there has to be a more accessible way to do this.

By marking up these subscripts/superscripts equivalents with the `sub`/`sup` elements OR by using the relevant Unicode chars, you are doing exactly your job: telling user-agents the "meaning", so they can know how to process the text, e.g. for in-document search ('CTRL + f' in browsers), text-to-speech (screenreaders), web search (search engines), …

If a screenreader wouldn't correctly read/announce `3²` or `3<sup>2</sup>`, it would be a (serious) bug which they should fix.

The only problem for such user-agents would be if people misuse these characters/elements. It's not relevant in this case, but maybe for other readers: When the subscript/superscript is stylistic only (and carries no new meaning by being subscripted/superscripted), you should use CSS (instead of the special Unicode characters or `sub`/`sup` elements): [vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) with `sub`/`super` (and you'd have to adjust the font size, too. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572967/1591669) to a different question.)

Comment: Phonetic superscripts and subscripts in Unicode are just that, phonetic characters. Unicode specifically discourages using them for superscript and subscript, and there's no reason to assume that they will work correctly like that. Certainly a screen reader encountering 2ⁿᵈ should not be expected to read that as "second".

Comment: @prosfilaes: Of course you shouldn't misuse Unicode characters (did I propose that with my answer accidentally?), that's why I wrote "Unicode equivalent" (equivalent of meaning, not look). If you want to superscript "nd" to indicate an ordinal number, you should use CSS, not superscripted Unicode characters (unless there would be a Unicode char for ordinal "nd") nor the `sup` element. I'm no native English speaker, but afaik using "2nd" (= not superscripted) would be correct usage, too … so the superscript would be decorative only.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer; I hadn't thought of using MathML.

Answer (score 6):

There is no other markup element in HTML to indicate powers. Even the `sup` element does not mean exponent; it means superscript, which in turn may mean different things. According the HTML5 drafts, `sup` and `sub` should be used “only if the *absence* of those elements would change the meaning of the content. But they still show examples like `<span lang="fr"><abbr>M<sup>lle</sup></abbr>`, where superscripting is stylistic.

The treatment of `sup` varies by browser, but we cannot really expect browsers to read `3<sup>2</sup>` as “three superscript two” or “three to the power two”. If they do such things, `M<sup>lle</sup>` will sound really odd.

Similar remarks can be made about the use of superscript characters, such as “²”. Their inherent meaning is to be superscripted, not to denote exponentation.

This also implies that you can reasonably consider using other markup, like `3<span class=sup>2</span>`. The `span` element is semantically empty, but it’s not that much worse than `span`, which has “presentational semantics.” The reason for doing so might be that [there is no really satisfactory way to style `sup` elements](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/#subsupsize); with `span`, you start from a clean desk.