# How to move up the st, nd, rd in the date using c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, date

My output format date is `14th May 2015`.

But the output which I want in `14` the `th` should raise little bit up using C#.

```
StrBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>Delivery Date & Time</td><td align='left' style='text-align:left;'>-  {0}</td></tr>", (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDeliveryDate.Text) ? "" : (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtETime.Text) ? Common.ConvertValidDateFormat(txtDeliveryDate.Text).ToString("dd MMM yyyy") :  Common.ConvertValidDateFormat(txtDeliveryDate.Text).ToString("dd MMM yyyy") + " at " + txtETime.Text)));
```

Comment: use <sup> </sup> tag

Comment: i tried that also but not coming

Comment: possible duplicate of [Superscript in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)

Answer (score 1):

The `<sup>` tag is exactly what you need.

In the event you don't want to do so. You can use css

```
position: relative;
top: -0.5em;
font-size: 80%;
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/j8au1pk3/

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)