# add superscript through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, superscript

I have a scenario where I need to add superscript for one of the products. Suppose that it is abc9. I need to superscript R between abc and 9.

For this I need to split word, and number through JS. I also want this only shown when we get page height as 800px.

Comment: Can you include code showing what you've attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use JavaScript? As I understand it, this is a content/style question, so HTML and CSS are your friends:

The "correct" answer here really depends on how the superscript letter relates to the content of your page. Does the fact that this letter is superscript have *meaning*, or is it just *stylistic*? Every rule has its exceptions, but when given the choice, HTML should be semantic, and there is an HTML element that may be relevant here:

> [The HTML Superscript Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) (`<sup>`) defines a span of text that should be displayed, for typographic reasons, higher, and often smaller, than the main span of text.

If your superscript denotes some meaning, use a `<sup>` element.

If it's merely a stylized portion of a product name, then use CSS. For using CSS, there are a number of methods, but I'd personally use relative positioning like so:

```
span.sup {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

For a more in-depth discussion on the pros and cons of different superscripting methods, see [Superscript in CSS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)

As for making the superscript text only appear for certain screen heights, you again don't need JavaScript and will actually have a much easier time using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
span.sup, sup {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-height: 800px) {
    span.sup, sup {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

When the browser viewport has a height >= 800px, the media query rule will kick in and the superscript text will appear.

Ultimately, usage would then just be to apply `<sup>` or `<span class="sup">` to the letter "R" already in the markup:

`<p id="example">abc<span class="sup">R</span>9</p>`