# Fix extra spacing above sup tag in mpdf with CSS

Tags: mpdf

Is it possible to adjust line height, padding or margin in mpdf?  I tried applying the code bellow to the css file for mpdf but none of the properties took effect, not even the background color.

```css
sup{
  line-height: .6em;
    top: -10px; 
    font-size: 0.63em;
    vertical-align: super;   
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Phasellus nec lectus in risus consequat hendrerit non eu elit. Fusce imperdiet, ante sed maximus 6<sup>th</sup>, nulla augue ultrices nibh, vel ornare ligula dolor sed est.<p>
```

[Front end screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAw9g.png)

[mpdf pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E94BU.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there are some ways to achieve this. Choose one of them and make the magic happens.

**CSS Stylesheets - included in header of HTML document or as  or as @import()**
[css-stylesheets](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html)

1. html tags e.g. `p { font-size:12pt; color:#880000; }`
2. class e.g. `.stylename { font-size:9pt; }`
3. id e.g. `#style { font-size:9pt; }`
4. In-line CSS style e.g.
   `<p style="font-family:monospace;">`

And the way that I prefer to use.

**Using a stylesheet file.**

The WriteHTML() method takes second parameter i.e. $mode. See WriteHTML() for details of this and other parameters.

**Example using a stylesheet**

```
<?php

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
```

Otherwise please read this article. It also can help you.
[Superscript in CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501671/superscript-in-css-only)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the problem I'm having. I am able to work with a stylesheet file with mpdf and can apply css to many of the tags like <divs>, <p>, <span> just fine,  but when it comes to the <sup> tag, none of the properties that I apply to it works. Plus the <sup> tag dosen't  inherit the line height of the <p> or the <body> tag it's in. It has extra spacing above the line of text. Take a look at the screenshot I provided.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @stackDru, 
I think I understood very well what the task describe.
You are simply trying to style the sup tag. If the above options don't suit you, have you tried reading the Superscript link above? There, I believe that you can have a better understanding about the functionality and limitations of the html sup tag. :  )

Comment: Do you have an example where this works in mpdf?  No even backgorund color gets applied for me.  I dont understand the solution you are saying.  If you are using mpdf with a css stylsheet, can you try applying the css code i sent to a <sup> tag to see how it works for you and let me see a screenshot of it?

Comment: I don't know how you installed the library on your machine, I don't know your setup. So the best advice I can give you is, start here. Step-by-step, take a breath first.
https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html

Comment: Spend two or three days reading the documentation and doing all sorts of tests. From the third day you become a master in the mpdf library. :  )

Comment: Be patient with yourself and absorb the manual because it's the best way. This will help you and save you a lot of time in the future. ;  )